# Get value from list item and assign to an application item

Tags: list, oracle-apex, listitem

I am new to APEX and I tried to assign a value from a `list_item` (based on a query with displayed value and return value) to an application item, and it doesn't work.

When I assign the value statically, it works:

```
:F1010010_RESP_ID :=111;
```

But how can I assign the value dynamically?

Greetz 
Tim

Comment: It looks like you are using [tag:oracle-apex], not just [tag:apex].

Comment: You're trying to assign a new value to the list or trying to get the selected value from the list into another item?

Comment: i try to set an application_item with the selected value from the list.

Comment: There are several ways to do this. What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a drop-down list control on a page named, say, `P1_MY_DROP_DOWN`, then `:P1_MY_DROP_DOWN` will have the value that is currently selected.  Normally, you'd just reference that page item.  If you want to assign it to an application item, though, you'd just do the assignment

```
:F1010010_RESP_ID := :P1_MY_DROP_DOWN;
```

Comment: Hello Justin, thanks for the fast reply. I solved it and the  problem was the empty value in the "page items to submit" field.